# Search entire html file for a letter, and sort paragraph using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am practising and I have an html file and I would like to search entire file and find all letter A's lets say, and then find all paragraph tags and sort words alphabetically.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<h1>Egone quaeris, inquit, quid sentiam?</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Poterat autem inpune; Ille incendat? Sed nimis multa. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quibusnam praeteritis? Audeo dicere, inquit. Polycratem Samium felicem appellabant. </p>

<p>Optime, inquam. Eam tum adesse, cum dolor omnis absit; Eadem nunc mea adversum te oratio est. Si quicquam extra virtutem habeatur in bonis. Quod cum dixissent, ille contra. Disserendi artem nullam habuit. </p>

<p>Eadem fortitudinis ratio reperietur. Urgent tamen et nihil remittunt. Quo igitur, inquit, modo? Ratio enim nostra consentit, pugnat oratio. Oratio me istius philosophi non offendit; Erit enim mecum, si tecum erit. Ita multa dicunt, quae vix intellegam. Praeteritis, inquit, gaudeo. </p>

<h6>At quicum ioca seria, ut dicitur, quicum arcana, quicum occulta omnia?</h6>

<p>Facillimum id quidem est, inquam. Paria sunt igitur. </p>

<p>Quid Zeno? Eademne, quae restincta siti? Traditur, inquit, ab Epicuro ratio neglegendi doloris. Sed fortuna fortis; Confecta res esset. Cur iustitia laudatur? </p>

<h2>Dicimus aliquem hilare vivere;</h2>
```

This is what I've done so far, if it is correct:

```
$.get('http://example/test.html',function(data) {
        $('.container').html(data);

        var content = data;
        var letterA = [];
        var letterB = [];
        var paragraphs = $("p");

        console.log(paragraphs.length);

    for(var i=0; i<content.length;i++) {
        if (content[i] === "a") {
            letterA.push(i+1);
        }
    }

    for(var i=0; i<content.length;i++) {
        if (content[i] === "b") {
            letterB.push(i+1);
        }
    }

});
```

How can I add color to those letters in arrays, or sort these paragraphs alphabetically?

Comment: Could you please share the html code so that it will be easier to post a solution?

Comment: @GopalkrishnaNarayanPrabhu added :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're practicing, try breaking down your goal into smaller subtasks and learn each subtask. Each of the things you are asking for have their own unique solution and would make for a lengthy answer.

All of the following should be Google-able:

- open or read file with javascript (and store the results in a variable)
- find all indexes of a specified character with javascript
- get elements by tag name javascript
- sort words alphabetically from a string javascript

Comment: Hm, I did that and I just logged the number of letters and it works, but how do I change the style of those letters? I just did a for loop, pushed elements that are === 'a' to my letterA array. @besseddrest

Comment: When you loop over characters in a string and push characters to an array, you are only storing characters, not elements, in the array. You are not modifying the original string at all.

Comment: Try one of the following options:
(a) use regex and the replace() method of JS's String object, or
(b) split() a string into an array, replace desired characters, and join() the array

Comment: I think I messed up from the start, var content = data; is not good for sure, should I put it to var content = $('.container').html(); ? You can see what I tried on top, I edited code if you didnt see. Could I do something like this: content.split("a").join("<span>a</span>"); in my for/if loops? Sorry for bothering you

Comment: No worries - I enjoy helping. So in your example, you don't need arrays. When you find a match (when content[i] === 'a'), you just need to change the value of that letter (so, content[i] = 'x'). However, if you change the value to something with a different length (content[i] = '<span>a</span>'), you will run into several problems with the loop, because you are changing the length of your initial string.

Comment: There is probably a better solution for finding all the 'a' characters and changing the color; iterating over every single character in a file is time costly.

Re: ordering the paragraphs, I would probably store all the paragraph nodes in an array ($('p')), iterate over each paragraph in the array, and sort() by comparing the first character in the **content** of each paragraph node ('L', not '<')

Comment: Eh I understand you in theory, cant do it.. Thanks for help anyway, ill try to dig more..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153177/discussion-between-besseddrest-and-grabnem).